# Xamarin Forms: maintain selected tab over activity restarts

Tags: data-binding, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

My main page uses a `TabbedPage` to group existing news into different lists. The tabs aren't fixed; they're built from a data binding operations against a collection that's retried through a web service call.

I'd like to persist the selected tab across activity restarts, but it seems like I'm missing something. Since there's no selected tab property (which can be set through data binding), I've tried to handle the `PageChanged` and the `CurrentPageChangedCommand` events. I'm using the `PageChanged` to set the selected tab to the previous selected tab and the `CurrentPageChangedCommand` is being used to update the persisted selected tab (I'm using the `Application.Properties` to make sure the selected tab survives app restarts).

Unfortunately, the events generated by the tab will always set tab 0 as the selected tab! Here's what I'm seeing (let's assume that my app was killed white tab 3 was active):

1. When data is bound to the `TabbedPage.ItemsSource` property, the tab will automatically fire the `CurrentPageChangedCommand`, passing the first tab (tab at position 0).
2. My code handles the event and updates the current persisted selected tab by changing the selected tab in the `Properties` dictionary. So now, instead of 3 (which was the value persisted when my app was killed), it will have 0.
3. Then the tab will fire the `PagesChanged`
4. When my code handles this event, it will try to update the selected tab. However, when it access the selected tab from the `Properties` dictionary, it will get the default tab (0) and not 3. This happens because the `CurrentPageChangedCommand` was fired before the `PagesChanged` event (step 2), completely overriding the previously persisted tab index.

This default behaviour will also give a bad user experience when the user refreshes the current list (pull to refresh) because he always ends up seeing tab 0 list.

So, any clues on how to solve this? How have you guys solved this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it can't be achieved using MVVM as `CurrentPage` is not a bindable property and `CurrentPageChanged` is an event.

However, there's no need to handle the `PagesChanged` event. You could record the index in the changed event like:

```
private void MyTabbedPage_CurrentPageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Properties["index"] = this.Children.IndexOf(CurrentPage);
    Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
}
```

Then you could set your tabbed page's current page after you have loaded all the tabs:

```
object index;
Application.Current.Properties.TryGetValue("index", out index);
if (index != null)
{
    CurrentPage = Children[int.Parse(index.ToString())];
}
// Subscribe the event
CurrentPageChanged += MyTabbedPage_CurrentPageChanged;
```

I placed the code above in the custom tabbed page's constructor and it could change the selected tab at initial time.

**Update:**

If you want to change the tabbed page's children dynamically, you could define a property to avoid the event being fired when you change the children:

```
bool shouldChangeIndex = true;

private void MyTabbedPage_CurrentPageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (shouldChangeIndex)
    {
        var index = this.Children.IndexOf(CurrentPage);
        Application.Current.Properties["index"] = index;
        Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
    }            
}

// Simulate the adjusting
shouldChangeIndex = false;
Children.Clear();           
Children.Add(new MainPage());
Children.Add(new SecondPage());
shouldChangeIndex = true;

object index;
Application.Current.Properties.TryGetValue("index", out index);
if (index != null)
{
    CurrentPage = Children[int.Parse(index.ToString())];
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the tabs are initialised after the constructor and can be refreshed several times after the first time they're rendered...btw, there was also the annoying flickering thingy...so, I've replaced the binding code with biding over the viewmodel and now I'm building the pages "by hand" so that I can set the selected page during construction

Comment: @LuisAbreu You could call the code above after your tabs have refreshed. Set the `CurrentPage` again each time you want to load new tabs.

Comment: The problem with that is that the pagechanged event is fired after the currentpagechanged event (that's what I saw in my code)...

Comment: @LuisAbreu I know your issue now. Please see my update.

Comment: Yep, that's similar to what I've done (in order to remove the annoying flick that occurs during rebinding, I've updated the code to set the selected page during rendering). Unfortunately, it means you can't use bindings+commands and you'll have to resort to writing the code in the view...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I had to abandon the MVVM approach...In the end, I had to resort to code and a couple of flags to control when the generated tab events should be handled.